# How to get the metricName from logs.MetricFilter instance

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

```
const adminErrorFilter = new logs.MetricFilter(this, 'admin-metric-filter', {
  logGroup: props!.adminLogGroup,
  metricNamespace: 'admin-error-metrics',
  metricName: 'admin-error',
  filterPattern: logs.FilterPattern.anyTerm("error","Error","ERROR"),
  metricValue: "1",
});

const alarm = new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'Alarm', {
  metric: new cloudwatch.Metric({
    namespace: 'MyTest',
    metricName: 'admin-error' // here
    //metricName: adminErrorFilter.metricName // error occurs
  }),
  threshold: 1,
  evaluationPeriods: 1,
});
```

I have filter and alerm like this, I put metricName for `cloudwatch.Alarm` as string.

So I try to use adminErrorFilter.metricName however it says `metricName is private member`.

Is there any method to access the `metricName` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`metric()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_logs.MetricFilter.html#metricprops) method to get a `Metric` instance, and access its `metricName` prop:

```
adminErrorFilter.metric().metricName;
```

Better yet, pass the entire metric to the alarm:

```
const alarm = new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'Alarm', {
  metric: adminErrorFilter.metric(),
```

Comment: Thank you very much , I see I need to load Metric instance once and then get metricName.